# Cant access website backup on Localhost?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have backup of a entire forum on my pc. I places in it in the htdoc folder in xampp.

But when i try to acces it i get following error

> **MyBB** has experienced an internal SQL error and cannot continue.
>
> **SQL Error:  1045** - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> **Query**: [READ] Unable to connect to MySQL server

I tried to remove password from inc\config.php but then i get following errors

> **MyBB** has experienced an internal SQL error and cannot continue.
>
> **SQL Error**:
>       0 -
>
> **Query**:
>       [READ] Unable to select database

Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Comment: Did you set up the database?

Comment: You also need to restore the backup of the database.

Comment: no thats why i am pissed off

Comment: I think that the first message is your solution. It smells like if you don't had permission to access to the database. Are you sure that the username, password or the IP of database host is correct?

Comment: @Angel I am not sure about that as It's not mine someone gave it to me, But ihave already changed the user name, pass, host, port to my machine but still i am getting the error

Comment: It appears that the database does not exist on your local machine. You will need to create it and the tables that are used in order to proceed